# How to combine Year and Quarter in R

Tags: r

I am trying to combine Year and Quarter to assign to new variable "YQ in data frame X02_4m_bb as coding below. But the output of new variable still NA? What's the problem here?

```
library(zoo)
X02_4m_bb$YQ <- NA
for(i in 1: nrow(X02_4m_bb)){
  X02_4m_bb$YQ[i] <- as.yearqtr(paste(X02_4m_bb$Year[i], X02_4m_bb$Quarter[i]), format = "%Y-%q")
}

 Year Quarter Revenue   CGS Gross_Profit_M Disp_Income_B    YQ
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
1  1995       1   1275. 1080.           195.        16351.    NA
2  1995       2   1438. 1228.           210.        16481.    NA
3  1995       3   1929. 1672.           257.        16695.    NA
4  1995       4   2576. 2246.           329.        16865.    NA
5  1996       1   1637. 1387.           250.        17122.    NA
6  1996       2   1779. 1510.           268.        17400.    NA
```

Comment: It works, just no " - " between Year and Quarter  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl> <yearqtr>
1  1995       1   1275. 1080.           195.        16351. 1995 Q1  
2  1995       2   1438. 1228.           210.        16481. 1995 Q2  
3  1995       3   1929. 1672.           257.        16695. 1995 Q3  
4  1995       4   2576. 2246.           329.        16865. 1995 Q4  
5  1996       1   1637. 1387.           250.        17122. 1996 Q1  
6  1996       2   1779. 1510.           268.        17400. 1996 Q2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a loop

just do

```
X02_4m_bb$YQ <- as.yearqtr(paste0(X02_4m_bb$Year, "-", X02_4m_bb$Quarter))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will work for you

```
as.yearqtr(format(paste(X02_4m_bb$Year[i], X02_4m_bb$Quarter[i])), "%Y%q")
```